# Why null variable still widen to type any when strictNullChecks is on?

Tags: typescript

[TypeScript Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#type-widening) said it should be no more type widening if `strictNullChecks` is true. And typeof `nul` should be `null`.

```
let nul = null; // typeof nul = any
let undef = undefined; // typeof undef = any
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=8#code/DYUwLgBAdgrsEF5p2AbggegxMBPADiAPYBmy8SAhlLgFCiQxQAmIZSTrJAllCM+iw4CxMpzaII1OkA)

Turn on `strictNullChecks` of the playground in TSConfig tab.
The type of `nul` and `undef` is still any. Why？

UPDATE:

Thanks @jcalz. I found something interesting:

```
// strictNullChecks=true;
let z = null; // hover on z, quick info shows: let z: any <--
type A = typeof z; // type A = null
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAXhC8EDsCuxgG4BQYCeAHEEAgnBDvgPYBm0aQA)

```
// strictNullChecks=false;
let z = null; // hover on z, quick info shows: let z: any 
type A = typeof z; // type A = any <---
```

[Playground (turn off strictNullCheck)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/DYUwLgBAXhC8EDsCuxgG4BQYCeAHEEAgnBDvgPYBm0aQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation you linked](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#type-widening) was probably accurate when TypeScript 2.0 was released.  But when when TypeScript 2.1 was released, it introduced [improved `any` inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#improved-any-inference), implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#11263](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11263).

From then on, if you enable `--noImplicitAny`, when you initialize a non-`const` variable to `null` or `undefined` (or don't initialize it at all), the compiler infers its type as `any` and not as `null` or `undefined`, even with `--strictNullChecks` enabled, and even for TypeScript code (as opposed to [checking JavaScript code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html#null-undefined-and-empty-array-initializers-are-of-type-any-or-any)):

```
let nLet = null; // any
let uLet = undefined; // any

var nVar = null; // any
var uVar = undefined; // any

const nConst = null; // null
const uConst = undefined; // undefined
```

The motivation seems to be that when you initialize a variable with `null` or `undefined`, you are very likely to change it later to something else, and the `any` type allows [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to do subsequent narrowings:

```
let x = undefined;
while (!x) {
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) x = "finished";
}
x // string
x.toUpperCase(); // okay
x.toFixed(); // error
```

Here the compiler allows assignment of a `string` to `x` (which would be prohibited if `x` were of type `undefined`), and also sees that `x` is of type `string` once you get out of the loop, so it lets you treat it like a `string` and not like anything else (such as a `number`).

---

Even at the initial assignment, the control flow analysis narrows the apparent type of these variables to `null` and `undefined` in a way that doesn't happen if you just annotate a variable as type `any`:

```
let nLet = null; // any
nLet.x // error, Object is possibly 'null'

let uLet = undefined; // any
uLet.x // error, Object is possibly 'undefined'

let aLet: any;
aLet.x // no error
```

So in practice you probably won't observe too many problems with variables initialized to `null` or `undefined`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/DYUwLgBAdgMuEF5oFdjANwQPRYgQygE8BYAKFnADoAPbXEAJwYHsGAaCAeQCMArEAMaQAlgGcIAB2ajRw7sEIQA5FFTAlZUJGRxISZFAAmIAGbCoIQ5hz4iZHVVo3GLdlz6CR4qTLkLlBsZmFoYapFr4ugBctoToZHi6NHTQzBAurGRZpABueAzQAGr5iCho1rgEJLklyMUF+kam5pYVsdkCzFCikFAAwl09parlKSPAZJ3d2gPTpYHNIW0LwZbZmvC0jUEtVmQA7gAWwqAQABQAhNQAlBAA3mQQEMIm5wCyeGCHlAwEhswAWzOtwAPBAAAyUACsty2EAARMExIdLPD4qQAL5kJy4HoMcwAc2xlDAzAAqhIJIw+nhRCBgW1mABrPDVagk5gAMWE1EsDJSGQY61IQA)

Comment: @aztack I updated this answer in light of ahejlsberg's [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45317#issuecomment-892446715) about "auto-typed" variables.  That led me to [ms/TS#11263](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/11263) and the [relevant documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#improved-any-inference) for it that was released in TS2.1.