# Type Widening for null or undefined

Tags: typescript, types

I am reading *Programming Typescript* by Boris Cherny. On page 123, he writes:

> Variables initialized to `null` or `undefined` are widened to `any`:

```
let a = null  // any
a = 3         // any 
a = 'b'       // any
```

However, I do not see this same behavior in my code editor. `a` is typed as `null`; the second line throws a red squiggly: `Type '3' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)`; ditto for the third line: `Type '"b"' is not assignable to type 'null'.ts(2322)`.

Has something changed since this book was published in 2019? Was the author just wrong? Am I using some weird configuration somewhere? Does anybody have any insights here?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68629966/2828341

Comment: [I cannot reproduce your issue](https://tsplay.dev/NBRkpN).  This sounds like "weird configuration" to me; could you provide details on your configuration?